# how to change text size of android-spinner

Tags: android, spinner

How do I change the text size of a spinner in android.
I have read that if you get your items from a resource (like R.array.items) you use ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(context, R.array.items, R.layout.textview), but what if a get my items from a list that changes, how would I then change text size of the spinner.

Answer (score 2):

You need to redefine 2 resource xml's

1. Adapter dropdown view resource
2. Spinner item resource

```
    Spinner spinner=new Spinner(context);
    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(context, R.layout.my_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.my_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

E.g. my_spinner_dropdown_item.xml resource can be defined as:

```
<MyCheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/simpleSpinnerDropDownItem"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight" />
```

where `MyCheckedTextView` class has to be defined by you (extending `CheckedTextView`) - so it's a place where you can define your text size/style - whatever